# storing values into a integer variable

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question about storing a value into a integer variable. Is it possible to store different id into the same variable ?
This is my problem, I would like to use a collection_select to save many id's. 
My code is actually working for one variable, like this :

My code :

User model :

```
has_many :pins
  scope :artist, -> { where(artist: true) }
```

Pin model :

```
belongs_to :user
```

Pin controller:

```
 def new
   @pin = Pin.new
   @users = User.all.artist
  end

  def create 
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save 
      redirect_to @pin, notice: "successfully created!"
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Pin/new(views):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select(:pin_maker, @users, :id, :pseudo) %>
  </div>
```

I would like something like that for my new views :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.collection_select(:pin_maker, @users, :id, :pseudo, { }, {:multiple => true}) %>
  </div>
```

But the variables are not saving in my sql table. 
So my question is : That's possible to store many id in the same variable (:pin_maker) which is an integer ? Or should I create a new table for that ?

Comment: `That's possible to store many id in the same variable (:pin_maker) which is an integer ?` => no

Answer (score 2):

pin_maker is user ? if so:
(IMO): you need a n-to-n associations and a table users_pins.

> ```
> Logic:
> One user has many pins
> One pin may be made by many users
> ```

On Rails:

Model User:

```
has_many pins, :through => :users_pins
```

Model Pin:

```
has_many users, :through => :users_pins
```

Answer (score 0):

Try has_many :users to involve your associations